# Multiple Target on one ApplicationLoadBalancer on same cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I am trying to create ApplicationLoadBalancer which points to two different ecs containers on same cluster and serve them by hostname rule or path pattern, first one get deployed succesfully but second one always stuck. there is no error but it jut don't work
But if I deploy on two different cluster then it work fine

is it not possible or I am missing something?

Comment: Are both containers in the same task/service? Or in separate task/services? I believe you'll need to setup two target groups. Can you show what you have configured so far?

Comment: they are in seperate service on same listener with diffent target group

Comment: I am trying to do aomething like that mentioned in this article
https://noise.getoto.net/2018/12/17/getting-started-with-the-aws-cloud-development-kit-for-amazon-ecs/

Comment: If they are separate services then you shouldn't be having any problem at all, this should work fine. When you say the second one "gets stuck" what do you mean exactly? Is the service failing to deploy successfully? If so that may not have anything to do with the load balancer. You still haven't provided any of your CDK code or any real information that would be necessary to help you.

Comment: yes second service failed to deploy

Comment: Regarding code my code is similar to this article https://noise.getoto.net/2018/12/17/getting-started-with-the-aws-cloud-development-kit-for-amazon-ecs/

Comment: If it failed to deploy then you need to look into the reason why. You have not provided any information that could be used to help you diagnose the problem so far. The failure of an ECS service to deploy is completely unrelated to the load balancer routing you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some Research I found the reason It was due to ENI as I was using AWSVPC Network mode which is default one. I had to switch to Bridge mode to deploy it successfully.